# How can I log queries with regard to the their transactions in MyBatis

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, logging, mybatis

I have a spring boot project (2.7) and I'm using Java 17 and I'm using this maven package for Mybatis : mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2.
And I'm using postgres 14 as my database.

In the logs I enabled Mybatis query logs, but unfortunately still I don't see logs of transactions.
I want to see which queries are part of which transactions.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is my application properties file :

```
mybatis.typeAliasesPackage=com.example.demo.dto
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.com.example.demo.dao.UserMapper=DEBUG
logging.level.com.example.demo.dao.TransactionMapper=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

and here is my mybatis config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false"/>
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.example.demo.dto" />
    </typeAliases>


    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mapper/UserMapper.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="mapper/TransactionMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As transaction is managed by Spring, you need to enable logging for Spring's transaction manager class. Try `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, as it was mentioned in the comment
I should have added this in the application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```