# How to enable transaction logging in a Springboot&MyBatis project?

Tags: mybatis, spring-transactions, spring-mybatis

I'm studying transaction propagation and would like the console to print logs related to transactions.
Is there a simple solution for achieving transaction logging in a Spring Boot and MyBatis project?

I'm aware that the following configuration enables transaction logging, but it seems to be applicable only to JPA, whereas my project is based on Spring Boot and MyBatis:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091496/1261766).